# Is the function strcmpi in the C standard libary of ISO?

Tags: c, windows, linux

I noticed that the difference between linux and windows.
strcmpi is in windows C standard libary implementation but it is not in GNU's C standard libary implementation.
Is the function strcmpi in the C standard libary defined by  ISO? 
How can I get the standard file? 
Thank you.

Comment: Note that "case insensitive comparison" is not a simple matter. Do you want one that behaves the same way in all locales, which is what you would need for parsing HTML or something like that? Or do you want one that works for the current locale (possibly mismatching the actual input text language) or that tries to work for all natural languages all at once? Do you want it to take into effect collating rules? Etc..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The POSIX Standard (aka, UNIX) has [`strcasecmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strcasecmp.html) but it's not part of C99 / ISO-C.

Note: If you compare the above reference with e.g. the one for [`strcmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strcmp.html) you'll note that the latter explicitly references ISO-C, while the former does not. An useful feature of the OpenGroup references.

**Edit:** Since the locale-dependency was mentioned as a complication, see the above reference for `strcasecmp_l()` which allows *explicitly specifying* the locale to be used for the conversion. Windows has [`_strcmpi_l()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59z8dwe.aspx) for the purpose, again keeping with its own naming conventions.

Comment: Are you sure it's part of POSIX? I thought Microsoft tried to be POSIX compliant.

Comment: POSIX compliance for Microsoft is an optional switch / something you need to request when compiling (to get additional headers / changed prototypes in some situations). Also, POSIX has been (and still is) evolving; MS at one point certified to a (really old) POSIX standard, which doesn't mean it kept up-to-date.

Comment: Also, re, "POSIX" - I've been using the term to describe IEEE1003 (The UNIX Standard as specified / certified by the OpenGroup as "Single UNIX Specification").

Comment: N.B. Also not part of C 2011.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's a non-standard extension. Unix-like systems commonly have a `strcasecmp` which performs the same task as MS's `strcmpi`.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, a quick CTRL+F in the standard returns nothing for `strcmpi`. This means that it is a non-standard extension (of which both Windows and GNU have a lot).

Comment: How can I get the standard file? Thank you.

Comment: JACK M: It actually costs money, but I usually do a quick google "ISO C 11 standard PDF".