# strcmpi integer without a cast error

Tags: c++, c, strcmp

I'm trying to create a program that removes vowels from a string, add them into a vector and then give the user the possibility of having the original code again.

In my code i have this:

```
char s[20];
```

And soon after i have this comparison:

```
for(j=0;j<tam;j++)
{
    if(strcmpi(s[j],"a")==1 ||
       (strcmpi(s[j],"e")==1 ||
       (strcmpi(s[j],"i") ==1||
       (strcmpi(s[j],"o") ==1||
       (strcmpi(s[j],"u")==1))
    {
```

So if the array is char and the vowels are char(""), why the compiler give me this error?:

[Warning] passing arg 1 of `strcmpi' makes pointer from integer without a cast

**EDIT**
As someone said the correct is s[j] == 'a', but that result in wrong way. If a put car the result is still car. Don't know why.

```
 if(s[j] == 'a' || 
    s[j] == 'A' || 
    s[j] == 'e' || 
    s[j] == 'E' || 
    s[j] == 'i' || 
    s[j] == 'I' || 
    s[j] == 'o' || 
    s[j] == 'O' || 
    s[j] == 'u' || 
    s[j] == 'U') 
 {
    s[j] = s[j++]; }
```

Comment: I think you missed a few blank lines...

Comment: <pre><code> didn't work so well.

Comment: Indent code with 4 spaces to start, don't use tabs. You can click on the orange ? to see more information / help.

Comment: `s[j]` results in a single`char` ie `'a'` while `"a"` is a string literal that converts to a `const char *`

Comment: "e" is not of type char (it's a string literal, not a character one).

Comment: The braces aren't balanced as it looks for me?!?

Comment: The parentheses in your `if` aren't balanced.

Comment: YoungJohn still same error.

Comment: Note `strcmpi` is not a POSIX (or any other) standard API call: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618697/is-the-function-strcmpi-in-the-c-standard-libary-of-iso . As far as I know it is Windows specific so I suggest you tag this `winapi` or similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Strcmpi` is for comparing strings. The first argument to `strcmpi` is of type char, when it expects a `char*`.

In order to compare single chars, `s[j]=='e'` is enough, or `tolower(s[j])=='e'` if you need it to be case insensitive. You'll need to include `ctype.h.` for `tolower`.

Comment: `==` is not case-insensitive.

Comment: Yes, first i was trying to do that, but that wasn't working. I will in the end of the question what happened before.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments to `strcmpi` must be strings, but `s[j]` is just a single character, not a string. You can use `==` to compare characters directly. To get case-insensitive comparisons, get the lowercase version of the character first and compare it.

```
for (j = 0; j < tam; j++) {
    char lower = tolower(s[j]);
    if (lower == 'a' || lower == 'e' || lower == 'i' || lower == 'o' || lower == 'u') {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `strcmp` or any of its variants.
Because you want to know whether the string contains vowels or not, you may want to use a substring search using `strstr`.

Answer (score 0):

You use function `strcmpi` incorrectly. It first parameter has type `const char *` while you pass an argument of type `char`. That is the function expects a string while you pass only one character.

Moreover this function is not a standard C/C++ function. So it should not be used.

You could achieve the same result using the following approach

```
char vowels[] = "aeiou";
//...
if ( strchr( vowels, tolower( s[j] ) )
{
   std::cout << s[j] << " is a vowel" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already been told that `strcmpi` is not the right way to check single characters. This is an answer to the edit to your question, where you ask about actually stripping the vowels.

If you want to retain the original string, you need extra memory for the string without consonants. You also need two indices, because once you have skipped a vowel in the original string, the indices are out of sync. Here's an example implementation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char orig[] = "Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.";
    char cons[sizeof(orig)];        // Make new char buffer as big
                                    // as the original

    int i, j;

    j = 0;
    for (i = 0; orig[i]; i++) {
        if (strchr("AEIOUaeiou", orig[i]) == NULL) {
            cons[j++] = orig[i];
        }
    }
    cons[j] = '\0';                 // Terminate consonant string

    printf("was: '%s'\n", orig);
    printf("is:  '%s'\n", cons);

    return 0;
}
```

The expression `strchr` checks whether a character is in a string. You can use it as a shortcut to spelling out all vowels in explicit comparisons.