# character repetition in a file - case insensitive

Tags: c, string, file, pointers

I wrote a program to count the number of characters in a file. I intended the program to be case insensitive. But I am getting an error printed as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp1;
    char c[100], f[20], k;
    int count = 0;

    printf("Enter the file name\n");
    scanf("%s", f);

    printf("Enter the character to be counted\n");
    scanf(" %c", &k);

    fp1 = fopen(f, "r");

    while (fscanf(fp1, "%c", c) != EOF) {
        if (strcmpi(c, k) == 0)
            count++;
    }

    fclose(fp1);

    printf("File '%s' has %d instances of letter %c", f, count, k);
    return 0;
}
```

In this program I got an error saying

```
warning: passing argument 2 of 'strcmpi' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

What can I do to correct it?

Comment: Hint: The datatypes (or just "types" rather) of `c` and `k` are not same.

Comment: This program can be written much easier if you just read a *character* at a time using `fgetc`.

Comment: You can use `tolower` and `toupper` to make one character lower / upper case.

Comment: I dunno why you even need strcmpi function if you are just comparing the characters just compare the character directly this is definitely overkill get a single character at a time a compare it normally i.e. `c==k`

Comment: And `strcmpi` is definitely [non-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618697/is-the-function-strcmpi-in-the-c-standard-libary-of-iso)

Comment: Listen to the compiler warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare characters case-insensitively, simply convert them both to the same case with `tolower()` or `toupper()`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    char f[20], k;
    int c;
    int count = 0;

    printf("Enter the file name\n");
    scanf("%s",f);

    printf("Enter the character to be counted\n");
    scanf(" %c",&k);
    int k_int = tolower((unsigned char)k);        

    fp1 = fopen(f,"r");

    while((c = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF)
    {
        if(tolower(c) == k_int) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp1);

    printf("File '%s' has %d instances of letter %c\n", f, count, k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should protect `f` with `scanf("%19s", f);`, cast `k` to pass a positive value to `tolower()`: `k = tolower((unsigned char)k);`, and probably output a newline in the last `printf`.

Comment: The signature of `tolower` is `int tolower(int)`, so it will automatically cast its argument.

Comment: `tolower()` is only defined for the values of type `unsigned char` and the value `EOF`. If you pass it a negative `char` value, you have undefined behavior.

Comment: The type should be `int`, the value has to be in the range that `unsigned char` holds. But `scanf()` shouldn't return anything outside that range.

Comment: `scanf()` stores the byte into `k`, a `char` variable. If type `char` is signed and contains a negative value (such as `é`, whose ISO-8859-1 encoding is 0xe9, hence value `-23` with most default compiler settings), passing `k` to `tolower` has undefined behavior.  `k` must be cast as `(unsigned char)k` to prevent this.  Furthermore, you should store the return value from `tolower((unsigned char)k)` into an `int` to avoid a different problem in `if (tolower(c) == k)` because `(unsigned char)'é' != 'é')` on systems where `'é'` is negative.

Comment: I changed the declaration of `k` to `unsigned char`. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Technically yes, but a tad sloppy: `scanf()` expects a pointer to `char`, and so does `fopen()`.

Comment: Yes, you did. `char` signed by default, which unfortunately is the default in many environments, is a plague. Turning warnings up helps identify potential bugs (eg: `warning: array subscript is of type 'char'`), but the functions from `<ctype.h>` go unflagged.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `char f[20];` is probably too short for many file names.
- you should protect against buffer overflow in `scanf()` by giving the maximum number of characters to store into the array: `scanf("%19s", f);`
- you should test `scanf()` return value to avoid undefined behavior if the conversion fails.
- you should test if `fopen` succeeded.
- instead of passing a `char` value to non-standard function `strcmpi`, you should convert the characters to lowercase via the standard function `tolower` from `<ctype.h>`:

  ```
  if (tolower((unsigned char)k) == tolower((unsigned char)c[0]))
      count++;`
  ```

  the `char` argument to `tolower` is cast as `(unsigned char)` to avoid passing potential negative values for which the behavior is undefined.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    char f[1024], k;
    int lower_k, c;
    int count = 0;

    printf("Enter the file name: ");
    if (scanf("%1023s", f) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("Enter the character to be counted: ");
    if (scanf(" %c", &k)) != 1)
        return 1;

    fp = fopen(f, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open file '%s'\n", f);
        return 1;
    }

    lower_k = tolower((unsigned char)k);
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (tolower(c) == lower_k)
            count++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    printf("File '%s' has %d instances of letter %c\n", f, count, k);
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- file name `f` cannot contain spaces.
- white space characters cannot be counted with this program as `scanf(" %c", &k)` skips them until you type a non white space character.

Consider using `fgets()` to read input and fix these shortcomings.

**EDIT** If you want or must use the function `strcmpi`, you should read the characters into 2 byte arrays whose second byte is a null byte, to make these arrays proper strings to pass to `strcmpi`, but this solution is **very inefficient**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp1;
    char f[100], c[2] = "", k[2] = "";
    int count = 0;

    printf("Enter the file name\n");
    if (scanf("%99s", f) != 1) return 1;

    printf("Enter the character to be counted\n");
    if (scanf(" %c", k) != 1) return 1;

    fp1 = fopen(f, "r");
    if (fp1 != NULL) {
        while (fscanf(fp1, "%c", c) == 1) {
            if (strcmpi(c, k) == 0)
                count++;
        }
        fclose(fp1);

        printf("File '%s' has %d instances of letter %s\n", f, count, k);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

strcmpi expects two pointers to strings.  But you pass k by value.  That's a `char`.

```
char c[100], f[20], k;
// ...
    if(strcmpi(c,k)==0)  count++;
//...
// fix:
    if(strcmpi(c,&k)==0)  count++;
```

You should maybe consider using the POSIX-conforming _stricmp instead of strcmpi.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to use `strcmpi()` for characters you can straight away compare two characters by:

```
if(tolower(c) == tolower(k))  
  count++;
```

Comment: This is case-sensitive.

Comment: _You don't even need to use `strcmpi()`_: this is somewhat misleading, actually using `strcmpi()` is plain wrong.